# How to get data attribute of select menu

Tags: jquery

I have the following code - when I try to log `val` or `id`, it outputs what I need. However when I output maximum, I get `undefined`. Any ideas why?

**HTML**

```
<select data-maximum="1" class="missing" name="15077" id="15077">
    <option value="0" selected>0 items missing</option>
    <option value="1" >1 item missing</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.missing').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var maximum = $(this).attr("maximum");
        console.log(maximum);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because when using `attr()` you need to include the `data-` prefix. That being said I'd recommend using `data()` over `attr()` and in that case you don't need to use the prefix.

```js
$('.missing').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var maximum = $(this).data("maximum"); // or: $(this).attr("data-maximum");
  console.log(maximum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-maximum="1" class="missing" name="15077" id="15077">
    <option value="0" selected>0 items missing</option>
    <option value="1" >1 item missing</option>
</select>
```

Note that `data()` will coerce the data type for you, so in this case `maximum` would be an integer. Using `attr()` will always return a string.

Comment: As soon as I posted it, I realised. Was doing it with the other answer and forgot to add the data- back in!

Comment: You could also use `.data("maximum")` - this doesn't require the `data-` prefix and will parse the result to the appropriate type whereas `.attr()` will always return a string.

Comment: Always happens :) I expanded the answer a little for you. I'd recommend using `data()` as the getter/setter over `attr()` where possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.data` instead of .`attr`

`var maximum = $(this).data("maximum");`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.data("maximum")` function or, `.attr("data-maximum")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.missing').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var maximum = $(this).data("maximum");
        console.log(maximum);
        maximum = $(this).attr("data-maximum");
        console.log(maximum);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-maximum="1" class="missing" name="15077" id="15077">
    <option value="0" selected>0 items missing</option>
    <option value="1" >1 item missing</option>
</select>
```